# MongoDB Date conversion. Need FIND statement

Tags: mongodb

Dates are stored in STRING like 1638811740593. How to I convert to standard Date. Help me with FIND statement (similar to select date(1638811740593) from dummy. Yes I'm SQL era guy :)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Change the date to Long using `$toLong`, then use `$toDate` to convert it to Date field.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "date": {
        "$toDate": {
          "$toLong": "$date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JQxLhiUEGjk) for your reference.